# Preventing Web API from mapping unintended routes

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working with route mapping in Web API 2 and am running across the following frustration.

I have the following two routes configured :

```
new
{
    Path = "api/widgets/{group}/{name}",
    Defaults = new { },
    Controllers = new[]
    {
        new { Name = "Widget", Type = typeof(WidgetController) }
    }
},
new
{
    Path = "api/widgets/{group}",
    Defaults = new { group = RouteParameter.Optional },
    Controllers = new[]
    {
        new { Name = "WidgetGroup", Type = typeof(WidgetController) }
    }
}
```

The WidgetController defines the following methods :

```
// 1) Create a new widget group
public IHttpActionResult PostAsync(WidgetGroup entity) { ... }

// 2) Create a new widget in a widget group
public IHttpActionResult PostAsync(string group, Widget entity) { ... }

// 3) Modify a specific widget in the widget group
public IHttpActionResult PutAsync(string group, string name, Widget entity) { ... }
```

Here is what happens:

**POST** api/widgets maps to #1

**PUT** api/widgets returns 405 method not allowed

**POST** api/widgets/mygroup maps to #2

**PUT** api/widgets/mygroup returns 405 method not allowed

**PUT** api/widgets/mygroup/mywidget maps to #3

All of this is expected and works as intended. However :

**POST** api/widgets/mygroup/mywidget maps to #2

I do not want this to happen.

How can I prevent this and make it return 405 method not allowed?